# Query a Query - MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

*I was recently trying to do a project*, which caused me to ask this question. Although since then I've found an alternative solution, I am still curious if what I envisioned doing is, in any way, possible.*

**Essentially, I am wondering if there is anyway to perform a MySQL query on a MySQL query result in php.** For example:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar=".$barValue);
```

AND THEN, be able to perform multiple queries on `$result`:

```
$newResult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $result WHERE otherBar=".$barValue);
```

OR

```
$otherNewResult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $result WHERE otherOtherBar=".$barValue." ORDER BY foobar ASC");
```

AND so on and so forth...

I realize that I could append the *original* query with my new `WHERE` statements and `ORDER BY`s, but that causes my to query the database unnecessarily and it prevents me from writing more objected oriented code (because I can't pass around a result to be queried, but rather have to requery the database in every function...)

**Any advice, pieces of code, frameworks, or ramblings appreciated.**

*BTW, my project was having to query a large database of people for people born in certain age groups and then query those age groups for different demographics.

### Edit

No, writing a custom function to query the database is not worth the object-orientation (and modifiability) it would give me

Comment: Why would you need to separate that operation into two queries?

Comment: I really didn't explain well what I needed to do. What I actually needed to do, was get a certain demographic from a table and count the rows, then I needed to search inside that demographic for another key characteristic, get those rows and find out how many people I lost, then I needed to repeat this cycle a BUNCH of times. For example: select all people that like icecream; then, select all people that like strawberry icecream and find out how many people i lost from last query; then, select all people that like that flavor in a cone and figure out how many I lost, etc...

Comment: It ends up being easier if I can query a result rather than having to reconstruct my original query with the extra WHERE statements appended to it... (although that is what I ended up doing)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do a nested query in the same SQL query and keep PHP out of it:

```
'SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar="something") AS q1 WHERE q1.bar2 = "something else"'
```

Comment: I was unaware I could do this :D

Comment: can you explain to me what the AS does?

Comment: "AS" used to make an alias, you can make aliases in mysql without using AS

Answer (score 1):

The question has already been answered. However following explanation will help someone who might be interested in knowing the details of it.

**What are Nested query / subquery:**

Subqueries are also known as nested queries. A subquery is a SELECT statement within another statement. MySQL supports all SQL standards and additionally provides MySQL specific features.

**Why should I use Subquery:**

1. Subquery is structured and it is possible to isolate each parts of statement
2. Subquery is more readable that complex joins and unions
3. Subquery provides alternative means to perform action which otherwise would require complex joins and unions

**What Subquery returns:**

A subquery can return a single value, a single row, a single column, or a table. These are called scalar, column, row, and table subqueries.

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subqueries.html
http://www.w3resource.com/sql/subqueries/nested-subqueries.php