# show users the position after sorting based on score

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which has the id column and score column, I want to sort the table based on score column and then find the specific user who is loading the page and show him his/her position. for example, tell him "your position is 40th".
Well I know how to sort a query:

```
SELECT id,score FROM `table` ORDER BY `score` DESC
```

But after the sort how can I find an specific id's position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an `order by` for this.  Instead:

```
select 1 + count(*)
from table t
where t.score > (select t2.score from table t2 where id = $id);
```

Comment: My table name is wordprogress21. should I change every word 'table' with 'wordprogress21' and that's it? because that doesn't work. I always use simple query, so I don't understand this query.

Comment: @coolesterman - just replace `from table t` with `from table wordprogress21 t`

Comment: Pseudo code for the query is: "Give me the number of all users + 1, whos score is higher than mine".

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 ‘rank’, id, score FROM table t, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r ORDER BY score DESC;
```

This will create a column and increase 1 in each record.

Comment: This worked pretty well, so how can I get the rank for an specific id in php?

Comment: After running this query in phpmyadmin, I get a table with a rank column. This table gave me all the records of my table, and I see the row that i'm looking for. I need the rank record of this specific row.

Comment: this is what I did `$query = "SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 rank, id, score FROM wordsprogress21 t, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r ORDER BY score DESC";` What I need now, Query this Query.

Comment: I found this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977408/query-a-query-mysql-and-php) and read it, but I couldn't solve my problem yet.

Comment: Your initial issue has resolved that u have posted in question for php integration u need to create one another question or update your question

Comment: Or also share the what u need in php.. how user can see his rank ?

Comment: @coolester-man: and u must add php tag in yur question and if u feel any best answer solved yur problm mark as acceptedc because this will help for other who also facing this issue